# Turning down meeting in the office

Tags: communication, colleagues

I'm completely burned-out and applying for other jobs. Mentally I've already quit although I perform all my obligations of course.

What makes it a bit easier is that I do home office 100% of my worktime. This is allowed at my company.

I'm allowed to work from the office, but I've just been there several times since I started working for the company 2 years ago.

Now a manager with whom I've been working for these 2 years, wants to meet up in the office to have a lunch together. He's not my boss, but he's senior to me. I proposed it before but he never had time. He now proposed several days and offers he would adjust to my preferences.

I assume he has a problem with my performance (bad) or wants to hang out and get some advice on the situation on the project (good) and I honestly don't know which is more probable.

I don't want to go. I just want to work my 8h/ day till quiting and then do something more interesting. How can I turn it down so that it doesn't come across as rude or burn bridges? It's possible that my job search will take 2-3 months longer.

EDIT: I have anxiety attacks even thinking about meeting him. Another manager asked me to meet him last week. I travelled 2h one-way to meet him. He resulted not to have time. A meeting that was expected to take an hour took 6 minutes and he visibly wanted to get rid of me as soon as possible. I'm not in a position to handle that mentally again.

Comment: Your instinct is correct. You need to find another job before you quit. But you should go to that lunch meeting. Don't tip your hand.  If he lives close to you, may be suggest a closer lunch spot than having to go to the office.

Comment: How far away from the office are you?  A 2 hour travel implies you are not in the same city as your company's office.  Do these managers know how far away you actually are?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, we are working in a complex, conflicted environment. We had some escalations lately. There was no fault of mine in them, which I think I've proved conclusively, but yes, it's perfectly possible that I will be blamed for them. I've already seen a lot of unpleasant situations and blaming scapegoats instead of addressing the real problem. No, my performance hasn't been bad.

Comment: Have you tried asking him for purpose of this meeting?

Comment: The tangible point seems to be that another manager asked (anything)… unlikely if this was in any way negative.

Meanwhile "I travelled 2h one-way to meet him. He resulted not to have time…" matters more for the language problem.

How could it be unreasonable for circumstances to collapse a meeting expected to take an hour, into a few minutes?

That he "wanted to get rid of me…" rather than explaining that a problem had arisen, does sound bad and that's not what you said, is it? 

Which part of it are you not in a position to handle again?

Comment: If you are burned completely out you may need to rest before starting another job. Be careful!

Answer (score 11):

> How can I turn it down so that it doesn't come across as rude or burn bridges?

You probably can't. You need to make a decision whether it's more important to you to maintain good relations with the manager or stay at home.

Answer (score 7):

You may need counselling.  There are signs.

> I have anxiety attacks even thinking about meeting him

Honestly this is way to much of a reaction to *just* meeting a manager without some very negative context to that meeting - e,g, a performance review or you expected bad news.

> I'm completely burned-out and applying for other jobs. Mentally I've already quit although I perform all my obligations of course.

This makes the anxiety even more odd.  You *should* be able to go knowing that you intend to quit regardless.  You might even find they have an offer that makes staying a good idea.  What's the harm ?  But your reaction is anxiety, well that's too much of a reaction and the wrong reaction.

> What makes it a bit easier is that I do home office 100% of my worktime. This is allowed at my company.

One problem with working from home is perhaps that it can create a very insulated lifestyle which make you anxious about going out and uncomfirtable with formal face-to-face situations.  You'd by no means be alone if this developed, particularly since COVID lockdowns.

Ask yourself if your reactions now are the same as they would have been before lockdowns and homeworking.

> I'm allowed to work from the office, but I've just been there several times since I started working for the company 2 years ago.

Meeting people online and face-to-face are quite different experiences.  You lose the body language and other haptic signals that are actually very important for communication.  The anxiety may be a result of being presented with a setting you've become less coomfortable with - a formal face-to-face meeting in business.

Don't underestimate how much this might affect you subconsciously.

> Now a manager with whom I've been working for these 2 years, wants to meet up in the office to have a lunch together. He's not my boss, but he's senior to me. I proposed it before but he never had time. He now proposed several days and offers he would adjust to my preferences.

Sounds potentially interesting.  A boss who wants to meet you may signal a possible career opertunity.  This is worth exploring.

> I just want to work my 8h/ day till quiting and then do something more interesting.

This may signal another issue related to homeworking : lack of variety.  It may be contributing to your desire to quit, because your day consists of spending too much time at home.  There's no boundary between work and home now and that makes it psycholgically difficult to keep them apart.  It can burn you out mentally.

Maybe you *should* go to the office more often.  This would let you keep up those face-to-face skills and create some variety of location for you.  It may also impress your employers.

> How can I turn it down so that it doesn't come across as rude or burn bridges?

Don't turn it down.  Go and see what they want.  It's an opportunity, not a threat.

> It's possible that my job search will take 2-3 months longer.

It's possible it could take as long as lunch.  I also strongly suggest you consider if working from home 100% is healthy.  Yes, communtes are tedious, but working from home is not ideal for everyone (and I frankly think it's bad for most when it's all the time).

Getting a good job may also require you to do a lot more face-to-face meetings and even take on roles where that's expected.  Senior roles are also going to require you *enjoy* meeting people, *thrive* on it in a face-to-face setting, so advancing your career will require you to demonstrate that.

Go to the lunch and use it to start reconnecting with the real world, not the online one.

Comment: I don't like this answer since it got some of the facts from my post wrong.

Comment: @user4u8003431 You'll need to be specific about what you say I got wrong.  I'm quoting from your own post.

Comment: I really don't like your answer since it ignores the whole context I gave. I did have the meeting in the end. It was to be a lunch. It wasn't. He didn't even ask about how I was doing, nothing polite at all - it was the first face-to-face meeting we've ever had. He used the hour to give me more useless work, ignoring completely what I was saying. I regretted I went and I will skip other meetings at the company. Oh, and I got a very good offer from a different team within the company a few days ago. My boss veto'ed it and made me turn it down.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it - on the business side - good relationships with your colleagues have a great impact on a team/company's performance.
And on the personal side, it is much less tiring to enjoy the environment in which you work and as you say - spend 8 hours or more a day in.

It's impossible to judge your case just by your question, but it seems that you had very little incentive to ever get to the office! Be it the Corona virus, children at home or other life circumstances and obligations - and that's perfectly fine! But it in my eyes it has the negative effect of depriving you that essential (IMO) communication.

My advice for you is try to go to that lunch. And if possible, find a constellation you're comfortable in, both professionally and inter-personally. From my experience at least - poor relationships at work caused me to burn-out, and vice-versa.

Comment: I agree with this answer, and would argue, there is a good chance the "completely burned-out" feeling the author is experiencing might be linked to the fact they are actually NOT going into the office.

Comment: @Donald: it's not. 99% of my collaborators are abroad anyway. The few times I went there I spent the huge majority of the time sitting in front of the laptop in Teams meetings anyway. My burn-out is a result of extreme work hours and complete lack of recognition.

Comment: @user4u8003431 - You have complete control over your hours, getting that under control, will likely help the situation.  The complete lack of recognition, that's more difficult to solve, since changing jobs won't guarantee anything changes (might become worse since you have to start over).

Comment: @Donald, I've received 2 offers in the last months: one was +30%, the other +70% vs my current salary. I turned them down because I think I can still do better. For me any form of recognition is ok, including the monetary one.

Comment: @user4u8003431 If I understood Donald correctly, he means recognition of one's self.

Comment: @Nexaspx - It's closer to being recognized, for instance winning a quarterly award, basically a "pat on the back". Going to a new place of employment might mean that sort of recognition might not happen immediately.

Comment: @user4u8003431 - Keep in mind there are other elements to a job other than just the monetary compensation.  If you take a job that results in a promotion equivalent to 70% of your current compensation, that likely will come at the cost of something, you might have additional money in your bank account without anytime to spend it with the people in your life.  If you already feel you are overworked, additional money for that work, likely won't help with the burn out. I took a job that was the exact same pay, but work location was closer to my family, but the actual work was more interesting.

Comment: I see your edition now @user4u8003431, if it's the case that you would be dismissed and this would weigh on you  i'd say do what's best for your mental health. And definitely look for places where you'd be appreciated in all aspects.